# How to install sybase extension with MAMP

Tags: php, mamp, mamp-pro

I'm trying to connect to a MS SQL server using sybase (`sybase_connect()`) with PHP 5.6.10 on my mac with MAMP Pro.

For that I obviously need the sybase extension, which is not included with mamp.

Can anyone help me with the best way to get a .so file I can add to MAMP and php.ini